# What's the criteria for swapping the order of floor and limit?

Tags: real-analysis

You can't always swap limits and floors.

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\lfloor\sum_{k=1}^{n}9\cdot 10^{-k}\right\rfloor=0,
$$
but
$$
\left\lfloor\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}9\cdot 10^{-k}\right\rfloor=1.
$$

What is the criteria for this?

Comment: You can swap a limit and a function when the function is continuous at the argument's limit.

Comment: The criterion to swap limit with any function is called continuity.

Comment: o swick thank u i should have rmemembered that from the class i took

Comment: However, we do have $$\left\lfloor \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\right\rfloor = \lim_{n\to \infty}\lfloor a_n\rfloor$$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\notin\mathbb Z$ or $a_n$ is eventually non-increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general one has
$$
  \lim f(a_n) = f(\lim a_n)
$$
if $f$ is continuous at $a = \lim a_n$.

In your case the function $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$. Hence if $a\not \in \mathbb Z$ you can exchange the limit with the floor function.